# Read files based on their modified time in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory, filesystemwatcher

I have a situation here. I want to read files based on their creation of last modified time. Initially i used FileSystemWatcher so that i was notified when a new file was coming, but later i realized that if the system on which my software is running goes down or restarts the location where files were being dropped will still continue.

To make it easier for understanding i will give an example:

System A  - File Server (Files are created every 2 min in a directory on this server)
System B -  My Software will run and Monitor files from the Path of System A

If System B goes restarts and is up again after 10 min the FileSystemWatcher will skip all these files which were generated in those 10 min.

How Can I ensure that those files generated in those 10 min of time are also captured?

Let me know if my question is still not understandable.

Comment: i guess there is no way , one way to do it is read file again on system restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to split it up in two systems, you have to persist a little bit of information.
You could store the current timestamp in a file, every time a new event was fired on the filesystem watcher. Every time your service starts, you can read all files from the filesystem that are newer than the last timestamp. This way you shouldn't miss a file.

Comment: This is exactly what i was also thinking about. But can you please help with a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I would split this application into two parts and running a filesystemwatcher-wcf service that buffers the files created in this 10 minutes and will send it to system b when it is restarted. I can't see a other way, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire files from the Source Machine and paste into the destination based on condition..

string dirPath = @"C:\A";
            string DestinPath = @"C:\B";

```
        if (Directory.Exists(dirPath) && Directory.Exists(DestinPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                string destinFile = DestinPath + "\\" + file.Name;
                if (File.Exists(destinFile))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    file.CopyTo(destinFile);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the FileSystemWatcher must write info about file system into DB (or other type of storage). When System B starts, watcher compares current file system with this info and will raise events about changes.

Comment: This is exactly what i was also thinking about. But can you please help with a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but based on what I get and assuming both systems are in sync in terms of time, if for example you want to get files that have been modified within ten minutes ago:

```
        DateTime tenMinutesAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
        string[] systemAFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(systemAPath);
        foreach (string files in systemAFiles)
        {
            DateTime lastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(files);
            if (lastWriteTime > tenMinutesAgo) //produced after ten minutes ago
            {
                //read file
            }
        }
```

I understood that these files are "generated" so they have been created or modified. If they have simply been moved from one folder to another this will not work. In that case the best way is to write a snapshot of the files in that list (and writing it to some sort of a save file) and compare it when it is running again.

Comment: Yes. May be some what Similar to this.
Along with @Marc and Vitone 's idea I can implement this code.. Let me try and get back to you.